# Button that actions on rows in a datagridview c#

Tags: c#, winforms

Can I have a button in a form, outside a DataGridView and on click of this button to perform an action on the rows of the DataGridView?

Comment: Did you try it before posting a question here?

Comment: No, I haven't. I am new to C# programming, winforms...I am trying to learn.

Comment: @AndreeaSuciu You can do whatever you want in programming. Subscribe to `Button Click` event and access gridView rows by `dataGridView.Rows`.

Answer (score 1):

Yes on this button click event  you can call datagridview event. Use DataGridView.CurrentRow property to get the selected row